# How to make VSCode completion model work with large amount of candidates?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, grafana, monaco-editor

We are using Grafana, which uses monaco editor which depends on VS Code.

We found a performance issue with Grafana code editor, I manage to trace it to some heavy code in VS Code.

This is the relevant bit: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/42fcfb8bfc975a450fcc7f32ce11ad0c4171a9b8/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/browser/completionModel.ts#L123

Calling `_createCachedState` with many items (in our case there's about 150k of them) is very expensive, and given its all synchronous computation, it blocks user input for seconds.

I wonder if there's any way around it? Maybe there's a better way to use the completion Model that avoid blocking user input?

My goal is to change Grafana to avoid this problem. I believe Grafana calls into Monaco using the code here: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/public/app/plugins/datasource/prometheus/components/monaco-query-field/MonacoQueryField.tsx#L199

Comment: "_monaco editor which depends on VS Code_" - uh... isn't it the other way around? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code#Features

Comment: Most monaco core functionality comes from vscode directly, as mentioned here: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: If that were the case then the Monaco editor could not be used outside of VS Code, which is however obviously done.

Comment: I am referring to the code dependency, not the runtime, you can read the contributing md I linked. Monaco editor's code live in VS Code as far as I can tell.